# Do we need to dispose object in an Excel .xlam addin?

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say we have such code as below

```
'Call service
Set xmlhttp_ = CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlhttp")
xmlhttp_.Open "GET", url, False
xmlhttp_.send
result = (xmlhttp_.responseText)

sendRequest = result
```

Do we need to dispose `xmlhttp_` after used?

Comment: It should be automatically disposed as soon as it goes out of scope. See Matthew Curland's response here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/3pw-TGc9PSo

Comment: @Tim that reference desrves to be an answer. I think I'll have to change my habits now...

Comment: @Chris - ha, yes I think I have never been really sure myself, but after reading that it seems clear that it's not required...

Comment: @TimWilliams Please make it into an answer to get accepted

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, please make this an answer. I planned to answer this, but you have it well in hand. ~JOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be automatically disposed as soon as it goes out of scope. See Matthew Curland's response here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vb/3pw-TGc9PSo